# Java JDBC - Column count does not match value count at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

```
                 String query =
                        "INSERT INTO hs (`username`, `lvl_1`, `xp_1`, `lvl_2`, `xp_2`, `lvl_3`, `xp_3`, `lvl_4`, `xp_4`, `lvl_5`, `xp_5`, `lvl_6`, `xp_6`, `lvl_7`, `xp_7`, `lvl_8`, `xp_8`, `lvl_9`, `xp_9`, `lvl_10`, `xp_10`, `lvl_11`, `xp_11`, `lvl_12`, `xp_12`, `lvl_13`, `xp_13`, `lvl_14`, `xp_14`, `lvl_15`, `xp_15`, `lvl_16`, `xp_16`, `lvl_17`, `xp_17`, `lvl_18`, `xp_18`, `lvl_19`, `xp_19`, `lvl_20`, `xp_20`, `lvl_21`, `xp_21`, `lvl_22`, `xp_22`, `lvl_23`, `xp_23`, `lvl_24`, `xp_24`, `lvl_25`, `xp_25`) "
                        + "VALUES ('"+p.getUsername()+"', '"+ p.getSkills().getLevel(0) + "', '"+ p.getSkills().getXp(0) + "', '"+ p.getSkills().getLevel(1) + "', '"+ p.getSkills().getXp(1) 
                                + "', '"+ p.getSkills().getLevel(2) + "', '"+ p.getSkills().getXp(2) + "', '" + p.getSkills().getLevel(3) + "', '" + p.getSkills().getXp(3) + "', '"
                                + "', '"+ p.getSkills().getLevel(4) + "', '"+ p.getSkills().getXp(4) + "', '" + p.getSkills().getLevel(5) + "', '" + p.getSkills().getXp(5) 
                                + "', '"+ p.getSkills().getLevel(6) + "', '"+ p.getSkills().getXp(6) + "', '" + p.getSkills().getLevel(7) + "', '" + p.getSkills().getXp(7) 
                                + "', '"+ p.getSkills().getLevel(8) +"', '" + p.getSkills().getXp(8) + "', '" + p.getSkills().getLevel(9) + "', '" + p.getSkills().getXp(9) 
                                + "', '" + p.getSkills().getLevel(10) +"', '" + p.getSkills().getXp(10) + "', '" + p.getSkills().getLevel(11) + "', '" + p.getSkills().getXp(11)
                                + "', '" + p.getSkills().getLevel(12) +"', '" + p.getSkills().getXp(12) + "', '" + p.getSkills().getLevel(13) + "', '" + p.getSkills().getXp(13)
                                + "', '" + p.getSkills().getLevel(14) +"', '" + p.getSkills().getXp(14) + "', '" + p.getSkills().getLevel(15) + "', '" + p.getSkills().getXp(15)
                                + "', '" + p.getSkills().getLevel(16) +"', '" + p.getSkills().getXp(16) + "', '" + p.getSkills().getLevel(17) + "', '" + p.getSkills().getXp(17)
                                + "', '" + p.getSkills().getLevel(18) +"', '" + p.getSkills().getXp(18) + "', '" + p.getSkills().getLevel(19) + "', '" + p.getSkills().getXp(10)
                                + "', '" + p.getSkills().getLevel(20) +"', '" + p.getSkills().getXp(20) + "', '" + p.getSkills().getLevel(21) + "', '" + p.getSkills().getXp(21)
                                + "', '" + p.getSkills().getLevel(22) +"', '" + p.getSkills().getXp(22) + "', '" + p.getSkills().getLevel(23) + "', '" + p.getSkills().getXp(23)
                                + "', '" + p.getSkills().getLevel(24) +"', '" + p.getSkills().getXp(24) + "')";
```

Not sure what the problem is, as you can see I have even declared the values to update (Taken straight from PHPMyAdmin after using an INSERT Query just to make sure I had everything right when I was trying to fix this. The table has exactly 51 columns, username, and then xp/level 1-25.

The server provides level 0-24 (Which fills up the 1-25 slots).

There are 51 updates, 51 declared columns, and 51 columns in the table.

Everything is spelt correctly.

if it matters I'm using **Statement->executeUpdate(String)**

```
value.executeUpdate(query);
```

Comment: Wow... 51 opportunities for SQL injection.  You should be using a parameterized query instead.

Comment: are you sure you want the ` symbols with the column names?  even if you do it should probably be ' or " this may of course be DB dependant you don't say which DB you are using.

Comment: Do any of the strings that you're injecting contain an apostrophe?

Comment: @JimGarrison - Highly doubt any SQLInjection will occur here, as it's server-sided code on a local protected database. The values being entered are all integers already defined on the server. If it's value is anything other than a number, it will throw a malformed exception. No SQL Injection here.

Comment: Also, why is the question getting downvoted? Because I'm not using a prepared statement? I don't need one for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Your database schema is badly denormalized.

You would be better off using PreparedStatement and binding values to parameters.

```
private static final String INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO HS(lvl_1) values(?)";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL);
ps.setString(1, "foo");
```

I won't do more than one column, because your example is heinous.  I'd normalize that schema if I were you.